# async sinatra with thin and rainbows in eventmachine. Why thin is more faster?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, sinatra, thin, eventmachine

I just launched [async sinatra benchmark between thin and rainwbows](http://github.com/francescoagati/async_sinatra_test_thin_rainbows) with eventmachine.

Someone can explain why Thin is faster than Rainbows with eventmachine and four work_processes? I also tried it with one work_processes but the result didn't change. Thin is still faster.

Thank in advance
Francesco

Answer (score 6):

Because I haven't profiled Rainbows yet for this use case. I advised Eric how to add support but haven't yet (over a year now I think :-/) had time to look into it.

Thin is quite a lightweight server, there's probably less overhead. It could also be outlier things like how you compiled the http parser.

Without more details of the platform, builds, and actual performance it's hard to say more. I can probably replicate though, I'd expect.

The other thing that's worth mentioning, is that my async rack hacks are not intended for /speed/ as much as concurrency. Many speed oriented benchmarks are not really appropriate.